# Android Emulator Returns Wrong Date

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to get the date in Android using this code

```
        final Date df = new Date();
        final DateFormat dft;
        dft = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
        final String  dftX = dft.format(df).toString();
```

This works but it returns as 11/03/10 instead of 12/03/10. The emulator appears to be showing the correct date. What am I doing wrong?

Rick

Comment: Please use code blocks to display code snippets! (I've edited the question for you.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you must add a "+1" to your month because in Date conversion the counting month begins with "0" as Jan and ends with "11" for Dec

Comment: Thanks Thrawn80, Shervin: That fixed it, forgot about that zero year thing.